# Shaking hands problem: 6 people each shaking hands with 3 others

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

There is a group of 6 people. An arrangement is defined as that each person shakes hands with exactly 3 other people. How many arrangements are there?

Follow up: what if there are $N$ people where $N > 3$?

Comment: Rephrased:  How many [3-regular graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_graph) on six vertices are there?

Comment: $K_{3,3}$ and a "triangular prism".

Comment: @JMoravitz It is an interesting lead.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit I'm not sure what $K_{3,3}$ means and why triangular prism is related to the question. Could you please explain?

Comment: They are names of specific graphs.  $K_{3,3}$ is the complete bipartite graph with parts of size three.  E.g. if you have three boys and three girls and they each shake hands with everyone of the opposite gender

Comment: @JMoravitz I see. I think $K_{3,3}$ solves a subset of the question because the graph is not necessarily bipartite.

Comment: Correct.  And the triangular prism is the other type of answer.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

The first graph is what I would call a "Triangular prism" and the second graph is the complete bipartite graph $K_{3,3}$. I believe these are the only regular graphs on $6$ vertices with valency $3$.

Comment: This answers the question of how many *unlabelled* graphs there are.  The question of how many *labeled* graphs (*since its likely the case that the six people in the original problem are distinguishable*), we count further.  For $K_{3,3}$, we treat one person as "special" and we choose who the two other people on his side are in $\binom{5}{2}=10$ ways.  For the prism, WLOG let the top left be person $A$ and bottom left person $B$.  We then choose how to arrange everyone else, noting that each other position is distinguishable WRT persons $A$ and $B$, and can be done in $4!=24$ ways.

Comment: That would count the number of ways for $A$ to have shook hands with $B$, but it could have been the case that $A$ did not shake hands with $B$.  In that case, set $A$ as top left corner and $B$ as bottom right.  Pick who the two people who shook both $A$ and $B$'s hands are in $\binom{4}{2}=6$ ways.  WLOG suppose $C$ was one of them.  Then pick who shook hands with $A$ and $C$ in $2$ ways, yielding an additional $12$ arrangements for a total of $36$ different labeled triangular prisms and $10$ labeled $K_{3,3}$'s for a total of $46$ labeled cubic graphs on 6 vertices.

Comment: @JMoravitz Have you missed the case where A is at top left corner but B is at top right corner? I think the triangular prism gives 60. Think of the triangular prism as two triangles connected with 3 cylinders. First, segment 6 people into 3 and 3. It gives 10. Second, align Triangle One (say A, B and C) with Triangle Two (say D, E and F). It gives 6. In total, 60.

Comment: @YiBao You are correct, I made a mistake.  $B$ being in bottom left corner makes it so that there is a $3$-cycle containing both $A$ and $B$ whereas $B$ being in top right makes it so there is no $3$-cycle containing both.